Is different between pinter and int in linux kernel6?
I have a question, seems kernel6 has different pointer value between direct print pointer and transfer to integer.
My machine
# uname -srvmo
Linux 6.8.0-51-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Dec  5 13:09:44 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

User space code and result. Got the same value.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *p = malloc(10);
    printf("%p == 0x%llx\n", p, (unsigned long long)p);
    return 0;
}
# ./test
0x10ba9910 == 0x10ba9910

Almost same code run on kernel6, those value are different.
void    *v_addr = kmalloc(PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
printk("v: %p == %llx\n", v_addr, (unsigned long long)v_addr)
dmesg:
[  917.192601] v: 00000000d4eee80d == ffff91380ed04000

Is this correct, and which is the real address, how to get that?
And I remember those are the same in the kernel 4.4.150
# uname -a
Linux (none) 4.4.150 #37 SMP Thu Sep 19 10:43:05 CST 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux
dmesg:
[  325.654889] v: ffff880165ec1148 == ffff880165ec1148


kmalloc() is not the C standard malloc() and printk() is not the C standard IO printf().
The format specifier %p hides data that can lead to leaking information about the kernel memory layout.
For printing pointers when you really want to print the address, use the %px format specifier.
See further information in the guide How to get printk format specifiers right.

With your rating you should really think about marking the questio as a dup.

Also, putting the link to the 6y.o. kernel version while OP uses one from this year is incorrect. -1 because too many mistakes for so high-rating person.

So you downvoted your edit, nice job, so low-rated person!

With your comment I understand that I did the right thing(s). As usual most arrogant people on SO are those who have high ratings (but not too high). I assume you feel offended, that's good.
